# Total number of months (Count) between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server

I need to get total number of months in select query.

My table name is "Customers" and column name is "Createddate".

I need to calculate number of months between "Createddate" to current date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [`DATETIFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select datediff(month, createddate, getdate())
from customers
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
select datediff(month, createddate, getdate()) from customers
```

Also check [DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart
>   boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.

Answer (score 1):

Use the DateDiff method to specifying the difference of numbers between two months as follows:

select datediff(month, createddate, getdate())
from customers

hope it will help u..